# How to change the behavior of accents from ´ symbol to ` symbol

Tags: autohotkey, custom-keyboard

I have the following script for typing Spanish accents:

```
AppsKey::var := "´"

#if (var = "´"), var := ""
a::Send, á
e::Send, é
i::Send, í
o::Send, ó
u::Send, ú
+a::Send, Á
+e::Send, É
+i::Send, Í
+o::Send, Ó
+u::Send, Ú
```

If I run this then I have to type the ´ symbol (*Acute accent - spacing acute*) for the vowels to have the accent.
This symbol is not "easy" to type on a US keyboard, so I want to change that for the following symbol: ` (*Grave accent*)

The issue is, when I change it on the script all the vowels have the accent always, not just when I press de *grave accent* symbol.

I don't know why this is and haven't been able to solve it. Does anybody know how?

Comment: Works fine here. If I run that then I **don't** have to type the ´ symbol  for the vowels to have the accent.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. What I'm trying to accomplish is having my English layout keyboard with an option where I can type a symbol, followed by a vowel, and make that vowel have an accent. 
The least used symbol for me is the grave accent **`** so I thought I could use that, but as pointed out by @Hovercouch that may not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you need is to use *hotstrings* instead of *hotkeys*, but declare a different escape character, so something like this:

```
#EscapeChar /
:*C:`a::á
:*C:`e::é
:*C:`i::í
Etc…
```

The asterisk in the first set of colons indicates that the hotstring will not wait for an end key such as space or enter to be pressed for the hotstring to fire. The capital C indicates that hotstring is case sensitive. What new escape char you use is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The grave accent is used in AHK as the [escape sequence](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/EscapeChar.htm) character. `` "`" `` isn't read as the string containing a grave, it's an open string containing a single `"`. You should be able to fix this back escaping the grave itself by writing ``` "``" ```.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I didn't know this! This "reverts" the vowels always having an accent. It doesn't solve what I'm trying to do though. I had a script where I could have the vowel with an accent by typing **right Alt + the vowel**, but that doesn't work for me because I repeatedly make a mistake and type either the spacebar or option/windows key. Do you have any suggestions on how can I solve this?